# DbSet outside of DbContext class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My project has couple of `Areas` which each one of them has their own entities and I'm trying to keep everything isolate in that area... (lets call those areas = `plugins`)

**DbContext**

```
public class PortalDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

**IUnitOfWork**

```
 public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        int SaveChanges();
        IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    }
```

**Service.cs**

```
public class PageService : IPage
{
    public readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    public readonly IDbSet<Pages> _page;

    public PageService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _page = uow.Set<Pages>();
    }
}
```

**Finally When I try**:

```
public void AddPage(PageModel m)
{
    _page.Add(m);
}
```

I get this error: 
`The entity type Pages is not part of the model for the current context`

this means `uow.Set<Pages>();` doesn't worked properly. 
is it possible to `DbSet` out of `DbContext` class is ASP.Net MVC code first?

Comment: You have to have some actual concrete `DbSet<SomeEntity>` properties on your context, otherwise it doesn't know how to mapp your entities to the database. Your `IUnitOfWork` interface does not really make much sense to me, what is it's purpose?

Comment: too bad, you know I wanted to have a simple pluggable architecture. In this case I have to change DbContext for each plugin.
that `IUnitOfWork` does `context.SaveChanges()` and `context.Set<TEntity>();`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this error message

> The entity type Pages is not part of the model for the current context

means, that the type `PageModel` was not configured as an entity type for the `PortalDbContext` context instance. You should either follow conventions to build your model (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962) page, "Type Discovery" paragraph), or build model manually, using [fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617).

The second scenario fits dynamic models for plugin-based applications, because you can discover models types, using custom algorithm, and call `DbModelBuilder` methods to "assembly" model.

> is it possible to DbSet out of DbContext class is ASP.Net MVC code first?

In short, you can't use [`DbSet<TEntity>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) without [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).
Consider `DbSet` as a part of context (AFAIK, `DbSet` holds a reference to `DbContext`, which was used to create `DbSet`).

Since ASP .NET is all about stateless, usual approach is to create `DbContext` instance (or its unit-of-work-like wrapper), perform an action, dispose the context, and throw it away. Holding references to `DbContext`/`DbSet` as a state in web applications at least useless.

Comment: Can i have dbcontext without dbset and initialise that dbcontext?

Comment: @ManirajSS: if you mean "without `DbSet<T>` properties at all", then yes, you can. But to use that context, you have to override `OnModelCreating` and build model inside it.

Comment: Thanks.But I aware of `OnModelCreating`.I need database without any without any tables(no `dbset` and no `onmodelcreating`)

Comment: What for do you need it? May be, you don't need context?

Comment: Yes almost no need for that. I need to execute some seed query under that context.(I'm using LogDataContext (for Log4net) and Log table without `Dbset` )